# angular creating too many scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My application consists of a table of results (in a ng-repeat) with a pager and pageSize options. Each time I click on the pager or change the page size, a new request is made to the API and the data inside my loop is updated, cause new scopes to appear. I'm having aperformance problem since this is creating an incredible number of scopes each page request / pageSize request when I check batarang. Is there a way to control this scope creation? I'm using Angular 1.3.3.

**UPDATE**: http://jsfiddle.net/z561z7ok/

contains basically the items which are too much 'scoped', and the service serving the data. the pagination call sends a request to get new data.

```
<div class="pageFilter">
    <span translate="overview.pager_page"></span>
    <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" previous-text="«" next-text="»" ng-click="triggerPager(currentPage)" max-size="maxSize" items-per-page="itemsDisplayedByPage"></pagination>
```

```
    <div class="resultTable">
    <div class="head row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-5 col-xs-2">
            <div class="key col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 hidden-xs" ng-click="reverse = (sortOption == 'fruit_id'? !reverse : true); sortOption = 'fruit_id'">
                <span ng-class="{active: sortOption == 'fruit_id'}" translate='overview.table.fruitsystem_fruit_number'></span>
                <span class="sorting" ng-class="{active: sortOption == 'fruit_id', reverse: sortOption == 'fruit_id' && reverse}"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="key col-lg-2 col-md-2 hidden-xs hidden-sm" ng-click="reverse = (sortOption == 'end_date'? !reverse : true); sortOption = 'end_date'">
                <span ng-class="{active: sortOption == 'end_date'}" translate='overview.table.fruit_end'></span>
                <span class="sorting" ng-class="{active: sortOption == 'end_date', reverse: sortOption == 'end_date' && reverse}"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="key col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 description" ng-click="reverse = (sortOption == 'description_short'? !reverse : true); sortOption = 'description_short'">
                <span ng-class="{active: sortOption == 'description_short'}" translate='overview.table.fruit_material'></span>
                <span class="sorting" ng-class="{active: sortOption == 'description_short', reverse: sortOption == 'description_short' && reverse}"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="key col-lg-2 col-md-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm" ng-click="reverse = (sortOption == 'check_in_material_number'? !reverse : true); sortOption = 'check_in_material_number'">
                <span ng-class="{active: sortOption == 'check_in_material_number'}" translate='overview.table.fruit_material_number'></span>
                <span class="sorting" ng-class="{active: sortOption == 'check_in_material_number', reverse: sortOption == 'check_in_material_number' && reverse}"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-7 col-xs-10">
            <div class="key col-lg-2 hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md" ng-click="reverse = (sortOption == 'last_polling_date'? !reverse : true); sortOption = 'last_polling_date'">
                <span ng-class="{active: sortOption == 'last_polling_date'}" translate='overview.table.fruit_last_request'></span>
                <span class="sorting" ng-class="{active: sortOption == 'last_polling_date', reverse: sortOption == 'last_polling_date' && reverse}"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="key col-lg-2 hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md" ng-click="reverse = (sortOption == 'stock_amount_prediction'? !reverse : true); sortOption = 'stock_amount_prediction'">
                <span ng-class="{active: sortOption == 'stock_amount_prediction'}" translate='overview.table.fruit_stock_amount'></span>
                <span class="sorting" ng-class="{active: sortOption == 'stock_amount_prediction', reverse: sortOption == 'stock_amount_prediction' && reverse}"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="key col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 materialUnit" ng-click="reverse = (sortOption == 'measurement_unit'? !reverse : true); sortOption = 'measurement_unit'">
                <span ng-class="{active: sortOption == 'measurement_unit'}" translate='overview.table.fruit_material_unit'></span>
                <span class="sorting" ng-class="{active: sortOption == 'measurement_unit', reverse: sortOption == 'measurement_unit' && reverse}"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="key col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 actions">
                <span translate='overview.table.fruit_actions'></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row result" ng-if="noFruits">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" translate="overview.table.no_results"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row result" ng-repeat="fruit in fruits" ng-show="fruits.length > 0">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-2">
            <div class="value col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 hidden-xs fruitNumber">
                <a cm-tooltip ng-click="openFruit(fruit.fruit_id)" ng-bind-html="fruit.fruit_id | highlight:searchText"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="dates value col-lg-2 col-md-2 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                <span cm-tooltip ng-bind-html="(fruit.end_date | date | highlight:searchText) || '-'"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="value col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 description">
                <a cm-tooltip ng-click="openProduct(fruit.id)" ng-bind-html="fruit.description_short | highlight:searchText"></a>
            </div>
            <div cm-tooltip class="value col-lg-2 col-md-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm" ng-bind-html="(fruit.check_in_material_number | highlight:searchText) || '-'">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Service:

```
services.factory('fruitsCollectionService', ['$rootScope', '$http',
function($rootScope, $http) {
    var fruitsCollectionModel = function() {
        var collection = []
    };
    fruitsCollectionModel.prototype.getFruitsCollection = function(params) {
        var self = this;


        return $http.get(\\APICALL, {
            cache: params.cached == true,
            params: {
                //a few params
            },
            withCredentials: true
        }).then(
            function(response) {

                self.collection = response.data.fruits;


                if(response.data.fruits.items.length > 0) {
                    angular.forEach(response.data.fruits.items, function(fruit, key) {
                        $rootScope.objectCache[fruit.id] = fruit;
                    });
                }


                return response;
            },
            function(response) {
                // bring error notification to view

            }
        );
    };

    return fruitsCollectionModel;
}]);
```

Comment: You'll need to provide some code as to what you are doing (JSFiddle would be even better), just using an `ng-repeat` and updating data doesn't cause this scope explosion problem by itself (since this describes what pretty much everyone does). You should only have one array of the objects to currently display and use that for the `ng-repeat` using `track by` to specify the id field of the objects. Updating the array with new items will cause the display to be updated.

Comment: Batarang sucks, I wouldn't pay it much attention

Comment: sounds like you are sending more data than expected. You get a child scope created for every row of `ng-repeat`

Comment: With in each row are you using an ng-controller or directive that specify a scope? That would help explain the issue but without actual code or you reproducing the issue in a way others can test we can only speculate the cause

Comment: @Bill i added part of my example, hope is enough

Comment: @Artdias90 you should details on how large the result set is? are you caching pages locally? how large is a page if different from the entire returned result set?